# Reading a file inside wwwroot in Blazor Web Assembly ASP.NET Core hosted

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

When creating a new **Blazor Web Assembly** solution from Visual Studio 2019 Preview (keep ASP.NET Core hosted unchecked), we have the possibility to perform a `GetFromJsonAsync` directly from a file located inside the  `wwwroot`.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
}
```

When creating a new **Blazor Web Assembly** solution from Visual Studio 2019 Preview (with ASP.NET Core hosted checked), we have the possibility to perform a `GetFromJsonAsync` by calling an action from our
controller `WeatherForecastController`.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
}
```

My question is: and what if in this second scenario (ASP.NET Core hosted) I would like to get data from a file located inside my `wwwroot` ? Is this not possible ? Security concern ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if in ASP.NET Core hosted I would like to get data from a file located inside my wwwroot ?

When you try it you will see that that just works. Those two ways of using HttpClient are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: You are right. I had another issue in my app causing the problem. Thanks.